# Getting custom Pod to work with Google Pods

Tags: xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, google-places

I've been trying for more than a week now to get my custom Pod to work.  It depends on both GooglePlaces and GoogleMaps Api's.  I figured out how to get a local Pod working for un-dependent swift code.  But as soon as I introduce one of those Google pods into the mix I get the error:

> [!] The 'Pods-testPlaceSetterPod' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/testPlaceSetterPod/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework)

I'll get the same error for Google Maps.

I've looked at the Cocoapods github issues section but all the conversations are beyond my level of knowledge. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with Google Mobile Ads. After hours of searching the short answer is **you can't do it with Swift**. I'm not a Cocoapod expert, and as your error states, Google distributes their SDK's as static binaries (opposed to dynamic) which won't work. The technical reasoning is beyond my knowledge but I did [find a post](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5624) that pushed me to quit trying

> Until GoogleMaps is released as a dynamic framework, you can only
>   support it as a transitive dependency as a library. However, as you
>   are using a swift framework - you can't support that either. Your best option is to request Google release their libraries as a dynamic framework I'm afraid.

I did come up with a solution that I thought was as good as I could get. Instead of distributing my project as a Cocoapod in your `Podfile` I added a few lines to include the Google SDK and download the file I *wanted* to distribute as a pod.

Have a look at [McAdViewController](https://github.com/kmcgill88/McAdViewController#installation), under the `Installation` section. Basically I add the Google Mobile Ads pod like normal and added some Ruby to download the latest copy of `McAdViewController` each time I do a `pod install` or `pod update`.

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.19'

puts "Downloading McAdViewController..."
require 'open-uri'
open('./McAdViewController.swift', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmcgill88/McAdViewController/master/McAdViewControllerExample/McAdViewController.swift').read
end
puts "Successfully downloaded McAdViewController! :)"
```

If someone knows a better way to change this to a legit pod, I'd love to hear it!

Good luck!